# Variable undefined even when it is declared as final variable

Tags: flutter

why is the variable showing undefined? i clearly declared it above. any help is highly appreciated...i even tried declaring the variable as string, still didn't work

```
  createUser() async {
//Todo: check if user exists in database

GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
final doc = await usersRef.doc(user.id).get();

//Todo: if user don't exist then take them to set profile page

if (!doc.exists) {
  final username = await Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount()));
}
//Todo: get user name from create account and create a new user

usersRef.doc(user.id).set({
  "id": user.id,
  "userName": username,
  "photourl": user.photoUrl,
  "displayName": user.displayName,
  "timeStamp": timestamp,
});
```

}

[image: error shows undefined variable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is not accessible as you are trying to access it out of its scope. You just have to use it within the {} (brackets) in which you have defined it.

```
createUser() async {
    //Todo: check if user exists in database

    GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
    final doc = await usersRef.doc(user.id).get();

    //Todo: if user don't exist then take them to set profile page

    if (!doc.exists) {
      final username = await Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount()));
        usersRef.doc(user.id).set({
          "id": user.id,
          "userName": username,
          "photourl": user.photoUrl,
          "displayName": user.displayName,
          "timeStamp": timestamp,
        });
    }
    //Todo: get user name from create account and create a new user


}
```

Hope it will work for you now :).

Comment: I just figured it out, thank you so much..such an idiot move on my part...

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you are defining the variable inside the if statement and where you are using is outside the if statement. So in a situation when the if statement condition is false, there is no variable called `username` and that's why you get the error

You have to put the code inside the if statement in order to use the variable:

```
if (!doc.exists) {
  final username = await Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount()));
   usersRef.doc(user.id).set({
   "id": user.id,
   "userName": username,
   "photourl": user.photoUrl,
   "displayName": user.displayName,
   "timeStamp": timestamp,
    });
}
//Todo: get user name from create account and create a new user
```